# Webview + CSS3 not scaling images properly on smaller screens

Tags: android, android-layout, css

I am using a Webview and some css3 to load an image and have it scale to fill the screen on any size Android device.

Unfortunately, I am getting reports that on smaller screens, the image is not scaling properly and getting clipped. When the image is clipped, it is also not scrollable. I would like to get it to scale to fill the screen on any device, but if that is not possible, it should at least be scrollable.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>*************</title>

    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        html { 
            background: url(images/1_1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #page-wrap { width: 400px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; }
        p { font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 30px 0; text-indent: 40px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">



</body>

</html>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:background="#000000" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:clickable="false" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
<img src="images/1_1.jpg" width="100%" style="position:fixed" />
<div style="width:100%;overflow:scroll-y;position:fixed;height:100%"></div>
```

The div will be placeholder for all other contents of the page. I mean any other tag you write goes in it as if its the body tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have one picture in the html and want the picture fit the device in the width, you can just use this code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
</head>
```

If your html is complicated and you want control more details of the display of the html on different density devices, Something like using different CSS with different density device.
Read this android [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#DensityCSS). I think it will help you.

Comment: I went through about 8 possible solutions for getting the HTML I was loading from a remote source into my webview to not be HUGE or Tiny. This was the only solution that worked correctly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css specification for overflow, like this

```
img {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I can't say more about it without seeing the used images in html.
(Where do you use the image/ Empty body tags?)

Answer (score 0):

may it because you give backgroung:to fixed & cover,because "cover" will straech image to whole anoroid screen and fixed is stick image to background so it not scroll the image,but just content is only scrollable try to add more content on page and test your self...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it extensively, but the last time I tried to have images scale to the full width of any Android device's screen in a WebView, I ended up dynamically injecting some CSS code to leverage the [`max-width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) property. That appeared to work fine on about a handfull of devices I tested with.

To take advantage of the max-width property, I simply specified the maximum width to be relative and have it fill the full width by setting it to `100%`:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Obviously this will only scale down larger images (and not upscale), but that'll probably okay for most applications.

As a footnote: if you're showing just a single image, you could also consider loading it up in an ImageView. That would be the more 'native' approach and might give you more control over how it's being scaled and displayed.